# Error in reloading the application react native

Tags: react-native, npm, android-emulator

i'm new in react native whenever i'm trying to reload the application i'm getting error on my emulator screen i.e  could not connect to development server.i'm getting below error. Any help will be appreciated. 
 [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Firstly I would recommend to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look around the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), 
in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I would [post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help others to better understand your problem. People will be very glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to open in your device browser the url: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta (if it is responding go to step 2 - even with errors - if not go to 3).
2. Add the following line to your androidManifest.xml `Application` tag:
   `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, rebuild your native app and test.
3. In a terminal run this command: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta . this site is not opening in my browser.

Comment: This site can’t be reached

10.0.2.2 took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Did the packager start correctly in your terminal ? Can you reach it in your pc web browser ?

Comment: it doesn't start i just got the time out error. it doesn't even start i guess.

Comment: And can you reach it through you PC web browser ? (with the same url you have in your app error)

Comment: no i can't i'm not able to reach . it's not responding

Comment: replace 10.0.2.2 by localhost (still on your computer web browser)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189512/discussion-between-shabnam-singh-and-kornflexx).

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too.
follow these steps in order

1.

- try deleting your emulator and create a new one
- then restart your pc
- start react native & run android

if not solved

2.

- connect an android phone via USB to your pc
- turn on USB Debugging at your phone's setting
- now start react native & run android